# How should I handle exceptions when writing javascript library methods

Tags: javascript, exception

I'm writing a JavaScript utilities library for myself as a learning experience and my question is. When i need to throw an exception in my code when testing an argument or something should i use `throw new TypeError();` or `throw TypeError();` or should i not check at all and just let he operation fail silently? I'm not sure it matters entirely. Of course I understand the dynamics of exception handling but is it better for me to deal with those exceptional cases as the writer of the lib or let the user test for them? For example, if i or someone using my library calls a method from the library with the wrong argument type which should I choose if any.

```
var Lib = {
    method1: function( /* bool */ do_task ) {
        do_task = do_task || false;
        if ( typeof do_task !== "boolean" ) {
            throw new TypeError( "argument[0] should be true or false" );
        } else {
            if ( do_task === true ) {
                // perform some operation.
            } else {
                // perform some other operation.
            }
        }
    }
};
```

If anyone has any better suggestions please let me know. Thanks everyone in advance. btw this is my first question on this sight. is it too long? or is it an okay length? thank

Comment: If you can recover, do so. If not, fail and let users know why.

Comment: I apologize reading over my question i realized i never explained what the code was. thats just an example method but that is how i have been setting up the tests for the proper arguments.

Comment: okay thanks for the solid answer Will.So I'll throw the exception if I cannot recover otherwise ill try my best to fix things. Cool. Thanks man